# ffmpeg watermark first 30 second

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i v.3gp -acodec copy -vf "movie=w.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" nv.3gp
```

It work's fine, but i want watermark only first 30 seconds.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You can convert the logo into a 30 second video with png codec and alpha channel, and apply the video as overlay.

The duration of the logo video should be specified through the number of frames at the frame rate of the main video (in your case, v.3pg). For example, for 30 fps main video run:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i w.png -vframes 901 -vf "fade=out:899:1:alpha=1" 
    -vcodec png -pix_fmt rgba w.mov
```

The logo needs to be faded out; otherwise it will not disappear. Then use the logo video as overlay on another video:

```
ffmpeg -i v.3gp -acodec copy -vf "movie=w.mov [logo]; [in][logo]
    overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" nv.3gp
```

Alternatively, rather then ending abruptly, the logo can be faded out gradually, e.g. within 30 frames using `-vf "fade=out:870:30:alpha=1"`.

Comment: Invalid value '1' for option 'loop'

Comment: And it doesn't disappear     ffmpeg  -i w.png -vframes 901 -vf "fade=out:870:30:alpha=1"  -vcodec png -pix_fmt rgba logo.mov      
ffmpeg -i v.3gp -acodec copy -vf "movie=logo.mov [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" nv.3gp

Comment: Strange. Are you using an older ffmpeg? Try `-loop-input` then, or get the latest

Comment: ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i w.png -vframes 901 -vf "fade=out:870:30:alpha=1" -vcodec png  logo.mov //  
ffmpeg -i v.3gp -acodec copy -vf "movie=logo.mov [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" nv.3gp // it's work, but thereis no alpha,  i saw black square after fadeout. If i make logo.mov without -vf everything is ok, but watermark appears whole duration.

Comment: You did not pass `-pix_fmt rgba` option. Also, try the latest ffmpeg.

Comment: ffmpeg version 0.7.11, it's latest in freebsd ports, -pix_fmt rgba does not take any affect :(

Comment: @Dmitry-Shkuropatsky could you please help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10948714/765854)??? Basically when I try to merge a transparent video I get a black overlay instead of background effect.

Answer (score 7):

`overlay` filter supports timeline editing; you can simply read from a png file and then `overlay=enable='lte(t,30)':...`

Comment: @kev What a lukewarm comment. I love it.

Answer (score 5):

Realize it's late, but as I was looking at a similar problem I managed to solve this one.
It fades in with 0.5 sec from start, then fades out at 30 sec

```
ffmpeg \
-i v.3gp \
-loop 1 -i w.png \
-acodec copy \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v] fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=30:d=0.5 [logo]; [0:v][logo] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10" \
nv.3gp
```

Comment: how do you avoid endless encoding loop ( caused by -loop 1 )? When on the other side I use eof_action=pass[out1] in the complex filter and map it to the output, the output has no working audio. Any ideas?

Comment: @fiveDust Try the `-shortest` argument (see [advanced options documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)).

Answer (score 0):

You may cut the first 30 seconds, apply watermark to it, then join it with the remaining part.