# How can I superimpose an semi-transparent image on top of a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I'm making a lot of "title" clips for some video I have. I have a simple 5 second movie over which I'd like to center an image that will contain the title text (in image format).

This seems simple enough, but I don't know where to start...

Comment: Please include an image as an example so I have a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: The image will be fully transparent except for some centered text. I actually haven't made the images yet, I'll be making them with imagemagick.

Comment: have a look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160771/ffmpeg-watermark-first-30-second seems similar to what you want to do..

Comment: Why not use the [`drawtext`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter? If you want to do the image method see [How to add transparent watermark in center of a video with ffmpeg?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/1109017). It doesn't use the outdated `movie` filter as in Nico's suggestion.

Comment: if you get answer of this question please share ...

Comment: I actually ended up using the subtitle method (ASS), worked much better...