# ffmpeg overlay a watermark image on a video every 15 minutes?

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

So I have a snippet from a bash script that overlays a transparent image watermark onto a video file, like this:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i out.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" /outputfolder/output.mp4
```

Works beautifully, and fast.

What I really need though, is to have the watermark only show up at the start of the video, and then every 15 minutes through the video afterwards, for 30 seconds at a time.

Is this possible without multiple passes?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160771/ffmpeg-watermark-first-30-second) might be of help.